# solving for bias currents in non ideal op amp

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am trying to work with the non ideal model of the op amp and solve for the dc output voltage in terms of the bias currents while ignoring input offset voltage using the following schematic

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjTJqc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Using superposition I control IB1, and get that I1=IB1+\$\frac{Vodc1}{R2}\$ where IB1=\$\frac{Vodc1}{R1}\$, but I can't quite get the entire output voltage in terms of IB1.
Also, when I solve for the second current source IB2, I get the situation where there is a current source from ground to ground, which means no current, and therefore IB2=0, so I2=\$\frac{Vodc2}{R2}\$ 
It seems like I'm missing something here because my resultant d.c voltage is 
R2(I1-IB1+I2), which isn't really entirely expressed in terms of biased currents like I wanted it to be. 
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

When taking into account bias current, you still have an ideal op-amp model in there. So \$V^+ = V^- = 0\$ (since you have negative feedback), and the inputs to the ideal op-amp still have 0 current flowing into them.

Writing the various KCL equations for the \$V^+\$ and \$V_{odc}\$ nodes:

\begin{gather}
I_1 = I_{B1}\\
I_1 + I_2 = I_{out}
\end{gather}

Substituting in Ohm's law:

\begin{gather}
\frac{V_{odc}}{R_1} = I_{B1}\\
\frac{V_{odc}}{R_1} + \frac{V_{odc}}{R_2} = I_{out}
\end{gather}

Ignoring the second equation (because it doesn't matter for what you want to find), we can easily find that:
\begin{gather}
\boxed{V_{odc} = R_1 I_{B1}}
\end{gather}

\$I_{B2}\$ cannot be solved for, it can have any arbitrary value. The only thing you can say is it has zero volts across it.

Answer (score 0):

For IB2, the offset voltage it produces at the non-inverting terminal is 0V due to the short so that's end of story for IB2. If a resistor were grounding the non-inverting input then that's a different story and a basic offset of a few milli volts might happen.

For IB1 forget about R2 the output impedance of the op-amp can be assumed to be zero and this makes R2 redundant. So, IB1 flows thru the 100k resistor and creates an error voltage at the inverting input of (say) +10mV. The op-amp output then has to compensate this back to the exact voltage at the non-inverting input - it does this by adjusting the output voltage by -10mV.

If 100k resistors were in both inverting and non inverting inputs then there might be a +10mV on the non-inverting input and also +10mV on the inverting input - because the voltages are both the same the op-amp has no adjustment to do and the output stays at exactly 0V.